# invalid literal for int() with base 10 when trying to convert from string to int

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to programming and I've been doing the project euler questions in python. [I've been trying to do question 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) and ran into the error above. I'm not entirely sure what it means nor am I sure how to fix it. Here's my code:

```
class question8(object):
"""This question gives a 1000 digit number and asks you to find the largest product of 13 consecutive digits"""
def __init__(self):
       self.inputSequence = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

def productFinder(self):
       input = []
       num = '1'
       for i in range(0,1001):
           input.append(int(self.inputSequence[i:i+1]))


       largestProduct = 0
       largestPosition = 0
       product = 1;
       x=0
       y=0
       while x<len(input):
          y=x
          for i in range(0,14):
              product = product*input[x]
              x+=1
          if product>largestProduct:
              largestProduct=product
              x = y
              x+=1
          else: 
              x+=1
       return largestProduct
```

The error is coming from the line "input.append(int(self.inputSequence[i:i+1]))". Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using builtins like `input` as variable names

You can debug this line better by breaking it into components

```
   for i in range(0,1001):
       s = self.inputSequence[i:i+1]
       print(repr(s))
       input.append(int(s))
```

or even

```
   for i in range(0,1001):
       s = self.inputSequence[i:i+1]
       try:
           input.append(int(s))
       except ValueError:
           print("s = {!r}".format(s))
           raise
```

Better is to avoid looping over a range at all

```
inp = [int(s) for s in self.inputSequence]
```

Comment: This comment really helped and your solutions worked thanks! Now I gotta go learn about these exception things and repr().

Answer (score 1):

Consider this bit of your code:

```
def productFinder(self):
       input = []
       num = '1'
       for i in range(0,1001):
           input.append(int(self.inputSequence[i:i+1]))
```

as it gets to the end of your string:

```
>>> "50"[0:1]
'5'
>>> "50"[1:2]
'0'
>>> "50"[2:3]
''
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>>
```

1000 digit number

0 to 999 is a thousand steps

0 to 1000 is a thousand and one

0 to 1001 is a thousand and two

I think you're overrunning the end of the number into empty space.

Comment: Yeah you're right the final array had an empty value, thanks!